# Multi cipher CTR

Tags: ctr, multiple-encryption

What is your opinion on this scheme:

1)get IV from CSPRNG

2)set 3 encryption keys k1,k2,k3 (3*key_lenght) (KDF/PBKDF)

3)Use 3 ciphers in CTR mode like this:
The initial IV is encrypted using cipher1 with key k1 , then the iv is incremented and encrypted by using cipher 2 that uses the second key and so on, the output of the respective ciphers is xored with the plaintext to obtain the ciphertext.

Is this secure?

Comment: you may want to explain that better, I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: If this is a secure mode of operation? Using 3 cipher like this

Comment: I understand what you want to know, but you have not explained how the operation actually works with enough detail for the question to be answered

Comment: cipher 1 is used with key one to encrypt the IV, this is xored with the first block of plaintext, then cipher 2 is used with key 2 and IV+1, then cipher 3 then back to cipher 1... do you understand this ?

Comment: Yes.. incrementing the IV for the same block output is unnecessary with different keys

Comment: It's never the same block, it's the next block ...

Comment: @user1028028 Why would you want to do that? It's secure as far as I can tell if *all blockciphers* are secure, but it's very silly.

Comment: why silly? In order to break this, one would have to break all ciphers.

Comment: Based on your explanation, breaking one cipher would break 1/3 of the ciphertext

Comment: yes, this would be better than breaking one cipher and that resulting in breaking the whole ciphertext

Answer (score 1):

If by "encrypted" you mean generating a keystream, then what you propose is to use in the CTR mode
$$
C_i = P_i \oplus F_K(IV||i)
$$ 
the following function $F$:
$$
F_{K_1||K_2||K_3} = E_{K_1}\oplus E_{K_2} \oplus E_{K_3}.
$$
This is secure as long as you ensure that for each key all the used IVs  are different (i.e. are nonces). As mentioned in another comment, it is OK to use the same IV with different keys in the CTR mode.

Comment: You misunderstood... they is only one IV, the first cipher encrypts it and xors the result to the first block of plaintext, the second cipher encrypts iv+1 and xors that in the next block of plaintext

Comment: You mean you use just the $3n$-bit concatenation of three $n$-bit blockciphers?

Comment: yes, in essence that's it